# MessageID, servicename are null in axis2

Tags: apache-axis

I have written an axis2 handler , which captures messgaeID, service name, operation name details.. 
I kept the handler at InFlow/transport phase. But when i invoke the service(which is hosted in axis2) i get all these details are "null"

Anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting all values as null  in your handler is, at that moment message has not been dispatched to relevant service and operation. You will see set of dispatches are there in Inflow to do the dispatching. If you put your handler after these dispatchers then you will get the service name and operations name relevant to that message.

Comment: I have put my handler after the Dispatch phase, and now i can get service/operation details.. But still messageID is null..Why?

Comment: messageId is property of WS-addressing, http://www.w3.org/Submission/ws-addressing/#_Toc77464323. You have to engage the addressing module for your service and client.